# On my Android phone 7.0 the TEXT color is black when I configured to other color. What should I do?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, colors

In my emulator this works, but on my old 5.1.1 Android phone it works well but on 7.0 it doesn't.

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/registration"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="25dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
  android:background="@drawable/bttn_back1"
  android:text="REGISZTRÁCIÓ"
  android:textColor="@color/belepestext"
  android:textSize="12sp" />
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="belepestext">#cad4167c</color>
    <color name="atlatszosblack">#a9000000</color>
    <drawable name="selected_item">#dddddd</drawable>
</resources>
```

Here is the log but I can't figure out any mistakes or errors:

```
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/Choreographer: init sf_choreo_doframe   debug_Level : 0x4f4cdebug_game_running : false
D/ViewRootImpl@5e4753a[Login]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=false
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=72
D/ViewRootImpl@5e4753a[Login]: setView = DecorView@2d9c5eb[Login] touchMode=true
D/ViewRootImpl@5e4753a[Login]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
D/ViewRootImpl@5e4753a[Login]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
D/ViewRootImpl@5e4753a[Login]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true -476065792} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
D/ViewRootImpl@5e4753a[Login]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true -476065792} hwInitialized=true
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1
D/ViewRootImpl@5e4753a[Login]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 720, 1280) ci=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl@5e4753a[Login]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
D/ViewRootImpl@5e4753a[Login]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true -476065792}
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@3e2cdaf nm : com.example.kozma.versenynaptar ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@69715bc
I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=82
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@25bb945 nm : com.example.kozma.versenynaptar ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@3df189a
```